# Dictionary comprehension problem in python

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=['a','b','c']
```

I want output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: None, 5: None}
```

We can have any number of keys.

I want to create a dictionary with these two lists using dictionary comprehension in python and list A will become keys and other is value for key 4 and 5 we have to print None and other keys with corresponding values how can we do it using dict comprehension.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Use zip_longest with dict comprehension.

Comment: Anyway, just use `itertools.zip_longest`:  `dict(zip_longest(B, A))` no dict comprehension needed

Comment: `{a:b for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(A,B)}`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the dict comprehension is unecessary. `{k:v for k,v in whatever}` should just be `dict(whatever)`. It's like a list comprehension, `[x for x in whatever]` should just be `list(whatever)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True but the question states it is a requirement: _using dictionary comprehension_

Comment: Often, a good answer is "you should do it *this* way instead"

Comment: `{k:next(i, None) for i in [iter(B)] for k in A}`.

Comment: What does "We can have any number of keys" mean? Can `A` be shorter than `B`, and, if so, what should the output be?

Answer (score 1):

`[None]*(len(a)-len(b))` will create n (Here, it is `len(a)-len(b)`)) time None and you can use `+=` to add them in to list:

```
b += [None]*(len(a)-len(b))
```

And you can make a dictionary by using `dict()` function:

```
dict(zip(a,b))
```

Full code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

b += [None]*(len(a)-len(b))

dic = dict(zip(a, b))
print(dic)
```

---

**Note**:
If you don't know which is the longest list then you can use:

```
if len(a) > len(b):
    b += [None]*(len(a)-len(b))
elif len(a) < len(b):
    a += [None]*(len(b)-len(a))
```

In `len(a) < len(b)` case **None will be overwrite** and value of None and it will be last item in b. To **avoid that you can use `dict(zip(b, a))`** instead of `dict(zip(a, b))`. Then you should change the full code as follow, but **it changes your output**(Ex: `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None}`):

```
a = [1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

if len(a) > len(b):
    b += [None]*(len(a)-len(b))
    dic = dict(zip(a, b))
    
elif len(a) < len(b):
    a += [None]*(len(b)-len(a))
    dic = dict(zip(b, a))

else:
    dic = dict(zip(a, b))
    
print(dic)
```

Comment: If `a = [1]`, your code will output `{1: 'a', None: 'c'}`, which seems dubious. But I suppose it's unclear from the question what "we can have any number of keys" really means.

Comment: Because It overwrites the value of None and finale ends with c

Comment: Yes, I know - that's why I pointed it out. I don't think you should try to handle the case where `len(a) < len(b)`, because the question doesn't make it clear what the output should be.

Comment: I think so. I add them as Note so he can think of it. If there is any other mistake, please correct me! Thank you very much for guiding me!

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_maker(keys, values):
    dict = {}
    for i, key in enumerate(keys):
        try:
            dict[key] = values[i]
        except IndexError:
            dict[key] = None
    return dict
```

Comment: Hi, this won’t achieve the intended result. You’ll get an IndexError looking into values because you’re not properly handling the length difference and filling None.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy fixed

Comment: please provide a short explanation in your answer

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

The way to go is to use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), as already suggested in the comments. `zip_longest` uses `None` as default for the missing values in the shortest list, which is exactly what you want:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

out = dict(zip_longest(A, B))
```

. You can also achieve this without importing anything, by using `zip`, which will only consume the common start of the two list, then update this dict with another one which has the remaining values from the second list as keys, and None as values. [dict_fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) builds exactly that by default:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = ['a', 'b', 'c']

out = dict(zip(A, B))
out.update(dict.fromkeys(A[len(B):]))

print(out)
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: None, 5: None}
```